# Replicate Kafka Data from AWS Kafka to confluent kafka using Load alancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, confluent-platform, amazon-vpc, google-vpc

I have a use case to replicate `Kafka` topics and data from one Kafka cluster in `AWS` to `Confluent Kafka` deployed on AWS. The issue is, my Kafka in AWS is deployed in a VPC, say `VPC-1` that dosent allow for VPC peering with confluent cloud. I need to use a `Load balancer/Proxy` service deployed in another VPC say `VPC-2` that is peered with VPC-1 and Confluent Kafka cluster VPC (`VPC-3`). Also, VPC-3 is peered with VPC-1. What would be a idea Load balancer setup to point to AWS `VPC-1` so that that data could be then replicated to Confluent cloud kafka? Below is how the VPC's are peered and I need something to run on `VPC-2` and forward data from Confluent Kafka to Kafka in `VPC-1`. The data in source Kafka is few hundred GB per day.

[image]

Comment: you would probably need 'Kafka MirrorMaker', tool to replicate data between clusters.

Comment: @kus As I have mentioned, VPC-1 and VPC-2 are peered and VPC-2 and VPC-3 are peered, but not the VPC-1 and VPC-3. So cannot use the MirrorMaker tool. Also, I can only go out from VPC-1 to VPC-2 and not the other way.